# Not able to access all the java packages even after adding maven dependency

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

I have added the maven dependency for the selenium version 4(attached below). But still I am not able to access all the packages. For example, I want to use the **Container** class of the **org.openqa.selenium.docker** package. But in intellij, when I type *org.openqa.selenium.docker* , it is not recognising it and not able to resolve it. The dependency is already added in pom.xml and I have already tried refreshing maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: do clean install, rebuild project or restart intelij

Comment: Tried doing the above steps multiple times, but still no luck

Comment: Please try to build first on plain command line... check the output ..